# Fabric.js Canvas equivalent widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any flutter widget like fabric.js canvas? We want to do image editing like multiple images drag and drop inside the canvas, freetransforming the image and entire canvas should be zoom in, zoom out and like that.

Comment: What did you eventually do?